# Authenticator not working Retrofit Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, authenticator

When the call is made, retrofit doesn't jump into an authenticator. It's not called. Which could be the reason for ignoring Authenticator?

```
private val clientWithAuth by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Config.API_URL)
        .client(
            OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(AccessTokenInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(
                    LoggingInterceptor.Builder()
                        .setLevel(Level.BODY)
                        .request("Request")
                        .response("Response")
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build()

                )
                .authenticator(AccesTokenAuthenticator())
                .build()
        ).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(Api::class.java)
}
```

Comment: It's okhttp, not retrofit there. Authenticator is only invoked if the service returns a 401 response code.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much